# Vapor 4 - Create a route that lists all available routes

Tags: swift, routes, vapor

I want to create a route on 127.0.0.1:8080/help/routes, that lists all available routes (like a help page). How can I accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by printing content of `app.routes.all`

Edit your `routes.swift` file like this

```swift
import Vapor

func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.get("help", "routes") { req -> String in
        app.routes.all.description
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use routes.all as stated on @imike answer.

First, get an array of Routes from the Request:

```
import Vapor

func help(_ req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<View>  {
    struct Context: Codable {
        var routes: [Route]
    }
    
    let routes: [Route] = req.application.routes.all
    let context = Context(routes: routes)
    return req.view.render("help", context)
}
```

And then, in your help.leaf page iterate over that route:

```
<ol>
    #for(route in routes):
        <li>
            #(route.description)
        </li>
    #endfor
</ol>
```

Route has attributes to display method type, path and others.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an aside (I know it's not strictly an answer to your question but it might be useful to know for others), you can get this information from vapor directly (Vapor 4):

Go to the root directory of your project in terminal:

```
run one of following commands:
‘vapor run routes’ or ‘swift run Run routes’
(Depends whether you have Vapor Toolbox installed or not.)
+-----+------------+
| GET | /          |
+-----+------------+
| GET | /hello     |
+-----+------------+
| GET | /about/all |
+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Would be cool if you know and add in your answer the direct command without `vapor tools` it should start with `swift run ...`